# PHP checkbox dynamic name and retrieve correctly

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, dynamic

I have a quiz and one quiz have multiple checkbox questions. How to make all the checkbox name differently so I can retrieve correctly?

Html:

```
foreach($questionSetArr as $question){
$questionID = $question['question_id'];
           $getListOfOptions = getOptionsList($questionID);
           foreach($getListOfOptions as $option){
               $optionDesc =  $option['option_desc'];
               echo "<div class='checkbox'>
               <label><input type='checkbox' value='$optionDesc' name='cb[$questionID]' id='$questionID' >$optionDesc</label>
               </div>";    
           }
}
```

PHP:

```
$questionID = $qIDArr[$x];
    echo "<br>User Answer for Question $questionID  : ";
                $selectedQuestion= $_POST["cb"];
        print_r($selectedQuestion);     
                foreach ($selectedQuestion as $sQ){
                    echo $sQ;
            }
```

Currently, they will retrieve wrongly.
How to solve it ?
[image]

Comment: Instead of using `$option['option_desc'];` use `$option['id'];` or such (presuming your storing ids)

Answer (score 0):

try name it this way:

name='cb[$questionID][]'